# What type of digital signature should I use for FIPS compliance

Tags: openssl, rsa, pem, fips

I am working with openssl to produce a FIPS compliant digital signature.

What type of digital signature I can use?

I used this command:

openssl genrsa -aes128 -passout pass:mypassphrase -out privkey.pem 2048

to generate a pem file but when I tried to load this as follows:

RSA *rkey = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey( bio, 0, 0, (void*)"mypassphrase");

I receive this error

error:060A80A3:digital envelope routines:FIPS_DIGESTINIT:disabled for fips'.

If I leave the passphrase off then everything works (in FIPS mode even) but that leaves my private key unencrypted.

Comment: I figured this out with help from openssl.  call set OPENSSL_FIPS=1 prior to creating the pem file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.